# Screenshots are taken when the webpages have yet fully loaded when using PhantomJS in python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

There is a problem while I tied to get screenshots by using PhantomJs & Python, the some of the images I got is not fully loaded.

I attempted to solve it by using `driver.implicitly_wait(5)`, but it didn't work.

```py
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.get("https://world.taobao.com")
driver.save_screenshot('x.png')
```

Dose anyone have clue about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I found to solve this problem is to execute a JS script to scroll through the whole page:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time


def take_screenshot(url, save_fn="capture.png"):
    browser = webdriver.Chrome()
    # browser = webdriver.PhantomJS()
    browser.set_window_size(1200, 900)
    browser.get(url)
    # scroll down to the bottom and scroll back to the top
    browser.execute_script("""
        (function () {
            var y = 0;
            var step = 100;
            window.scroll(0, 0);

            function f() {
                if (y < document.body.scrollHeight) {
                    y += step;
                    window.scroll(0, y);
                    setTimeout(f, 100);
                } else {
                    window.scroll(0, 0);
                    document.title += "scroll-done";
                }
            }

            setTimeout(f, 1000);
        })();
    """)

    for i in range(30):
        if "scroll-done" in browser.title:
            break
        time.sleep(10)
        print(i)

    browser.save_screenshot(save_fn)
    browser.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":

    take_screenshot("http://world.taobao.com")
```

Thanks to this original post: https://cloud.tencent.com/developer/article/1406656

Answer (score 0):

using`driver.implicitly_wait(5)` will be applied once to all elements present in the page for a maximum of 5 seconds and won't be sufficient in case elements take longer. Note that it will only have to be written once as well.
You can either add a `time.sleep(10)` using the `time` module or a similar waiting time if you're sure of how much time it'd take for images to fully load, or use explicit waits.

import the following

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Assuming you have the locator of the element you want to make sure is visible and want to locate it using XPath in this example (in case there are multiple elements loop through elements returned)

```
locator = (By.XPATH,"SOME_VALID_XPATH")
```

Define a variable to hold the `WebDriverWait` object as follows:

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(locator))
```

Problem with this might be that an Image can have dimensions and hence considered loaded and visible. A workaround can be to store images and assert the loaded images to be equal to them, which will be a rather complex solution to an easy case.

I'd suggest using either the `time` module or explicit waits.

[Link to the documentation](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html)

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't solve the problem in PhantomJS case, I find a way to handle it by executing a JS script to scroll through the whole page, it is posted below.

Comment: Glad you found it but scrolling through the page n number of pixels at a time is just adding a delay before you take the screen-shot. PhantomJS is just another web-driver and if waits are in place will take the completed screens.